# A software that resets trackpad option automatically

Tags: multi-touch, magic-trackpad

I've been running into this issue where certain trackpad gestures like 'swipe between pages with 2 fingers', 'force touch to show dictionary' or 'zoom in/out by pinching with 2 fingers' stops working for no reason. This happens like every 1 hours and the only solution I found was to recheck the options of trackpad action with the issue as the gif below. If there is a software that can recheck trackpad option every x minutes instead of me, that would be greatly helpful.

[image]